# How to configure Solr on few servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot-solr

I'm supporting on rails project, which contain rails app and additional instance with Solr 4.1. Unfortunately, clould provider is not so stable, and oftentimes some server goes on maintenance.

So, I think about how to make 2 identical search servers and some load balancer, instead of one... It will be more stable - if one server will be down, other will continue working.

My environment: rails 3.2.1, ruby 2.1.2, sunspot 2.1.0, Solr 4.1.6.

Is it possible to configure? Please, advise me a right way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: if you migrate to solr 5.0.0 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud otherwise you can think of scaling it by sharding and replication...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti also, what's a difference between sharding and replication?)

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti does solr 4 support SolrCloud ?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075423/whats-a-difference-between-solr-replication-sharding-and-solrcloud

Comment: SolrCloud which was introduced with Solr 4.0

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77083/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-bmalets).